# Which software development methodology?

Tags: project-management

I'm a member of a software development team, working on a small project.
We think that we can release a beta quality product after 2 or 3 month of continuos work.

Since this is our first teamwork, I decided to ask, which software development methodology would you suggest for a small project with small number of developers (less than 10)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "development method" here? This is a bit broad, especially not knowing what you are planning to do, how experienced your team is...

Comment: hmm... maybe you meant methodology? like agile, tdd, bdd or so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two approaches to software development:

1. Write down what you are going to do, do it, then agree that you have done it.
2. Start developing stuff, agree that what you have done is good, repeat until finished.

Both have their adherents and both pop up repeatedly under a variety of names.  Each new generation of software developers (ie about every 2 years, this is a fast changing industry and software developers have the lifespan of a mayfly) rejects the previous generation's approach, re-discovers the approach used by the generation before last, renames it something funky and declares it to be the ONE TRUE WAY.

The choice between the approaches ought to depend on the culture of (a) the customer organisation and (b) to a lesser extent, the culture of the supplier organisation (ie your software developer team).

So, if you work for a buttoned-down conservative enterprise approach 1 is indicated.  If you look down and see that you are wearing surf shorts and came to work this morning on your skateboard, go with approach 2.

And, in case you have read this far, the most serious bit is the paragraph before the one before this final one, ie the one starting 'The choice ...'  This is a cultural / organisational issue rather than a technical one.  Both approaches have been used on many many successful projects, neither has a monopoly on unsuccesful projects.

Comment: I love that answer.  I probably should point out that the two approaches can be used on different levels:  you could, for example, write down overall goals and use (2) to get there.

Answer (score 2):

This really does depend on what you are intending to build.  If the project is going to be something you want to build upon and have regular intervales something like Agile / Scrum would be very suited.

But it really depends on what the project is to determine release iterations and the like etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to start from **Joel Test** and try to implement most of this list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Joel_Test

And as product development use KISS = Keep It Simple & Stupid, for first release

Also really good start is Getting Real book, available free from 37 signals:
http://gettingreal.37signals.com/toc.php

Comment: I think that ampersand should be a comma! no one wants stupid software :p

Answer (score 1):

This really does depend on your customer.

- If the customer can accept fixed
  time, fixed resources, fixed quality
  (100% working code), and slightly
  variable scope, I recommend choosing
  an agile methodology.
- If the customer cannot accept the 
  above, i.e. the pre-condition for 
  using an agile methodology is not 
  present, I recommend choosing any 
  methodology you like.

The important thing is that you do have a methodology, learn what is working as you go, and use the knowledge to adapt the methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do waterfall, this never worked and will never work. Thinking waterfall is a working methodology is like thinking banging your head against the wall is good, because even the sturdiest wall MUST crumble at some point.

I'd go with a reasonable agile methodology, like Scrum (XP is a bit harsh). Also, introduce things like TDD, DDD, DBC and you should be fine.

Comment: -1: waterfall has worked many times.  No, I'm not going to justify the statement any more than @Turing Complete has provided justification.

Comment: Yes, waterfall works in the wet dreams of non - technical managers (and so called "consultants" - lol) in their ivory towers. However, its the worst methodology to develop software, I'd rather do RAD (which I hate) and cowboy style development than... waterfall.

Comment: I've seen waterfall work.  If you can decide ahead of time exactly what you're going to need, and implementation is straightforward, it works fairly well.  Its big weakness is that it is really inflexible to changing requirements, and it does really badly with experimental development.  One reason for its bad rep may be that the situations it's bad for are generally a lot more fun than the situations it's good for.

Comment: I too have seen waterfall work and for some projects it is the only real choice. Agile does not tend to work well for large scientific projects for instance where many, many things need to be thought out and designed in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wont suggest this as THE best answer, without having a better idea of the context and circumstances, but I am personally becoming a fan of the Lean / Kanban approach. In general I find a lot of the agile / scrum methods can be fairly developer focused, and almost anti-manager sometimes, which is sometimes appropriate but not always. The lean approaches tend to address the entire value stream rather than just the development itself.

You can read more about it at :http://www.limitedwipsociety.org/